# How to debug kotlin spring boot app in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to complete [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/) tutorial. App created on [this](https://start.spring.io/#!language=kotlin&type=gradle-project) page with gradle, kotlin, java 12, war, dependencies as described on tutorial by first link.
In a nutshell, all works fine, app build by gradle works, app starts, I can open gradle app in IntelliJ IDEA and start and debug works.

Next I want to compare kotlin app development in Eclipse. I can run app with this run configuration:
[image: run configuration]
App starts normally and works.

But in debug configuration there is no Gradle project option:
[image: debug configuration]

How to make proper debug configuration with possibility to debug kotlin files too?

Comment: What's your problem? Have you tried to run the app in the debug mode (should be icon with a bug somewhere).

Comment: I cannot start debug and set kotlin breakpoint in eclipse in spring app. After pressing on bug icon - eclipse asks to select debug configuration (empty list) or add new one, see second screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on project name -> Gradle -> Refresh gradle project did the trick.

Kotlin runtime library appears in libraries, java app or spring boot app debug now works, and breakpoint can be set.